# Allow traffic on one port from one IP address with iptables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, tomcat

I am using the following iptables rule to try allowing access to port 8080 from one IP address:

`iptables -A INPUT -s 12.34.56.78 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`

However, this rule isn't working. If I remove the `-s 12.34.56.78` part, then it works, but it allows anyone access to port 8080 (not desired).

When I run `iptables -L` after applying the rule above, I get the following (which mystifies me - why won't it just display the actual IP in the source?):

```
root@wso-solr:/etc# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  host-12-34-56-78.host.com  anywhere            tcp dpt:http-alt 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I'm wondering if this might be some sort of dns oddity that causes iptables to see the wrong IP address/DNS entry for my particular server (it returns the host-ip.host.com for source instead of the IP address...).

Comment: use --numeric or -n for numeric output of addresses and ports

Comment: You'll likely find it better to change the default policy to DROP (iptables -P INPUT DROP) than have it as accept with the last rule dropping all traffic. Less likely to trip you up in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was using the wrong IP address. My hosting provider identified the true IP of the server upon which my VPS was residing. I entered that, and everything worked like magic!