# Ubuntu on EC2 - How do I ip-restrict port 22 to a specific IP address?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

I'm lost in Linux, can somebody help me with an `iptables` command to allow only the IP Address 5.5.5.5 to access port 22?

I've got that port restricted to the same IP in the EC2 security group, but I need to block it on the instance itself as well.

Comment: "I've got that port restricted to the same IP in the EC2 security group, but I need to block it on the instance itself as well." Why?

Comment: I want to verify that I am protected from other instances. I don't think this is excessive. If I am doubling up, then so be it. I'm a programmer daggumit!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iptables: How to allow only one ip through specific port?](http://serverfault.com/questions/146569/iptables-how-to-allow-only-one-ip-through-specific-port)

Comment: If you knew more about how virtual machines worked and how the network devices are "wired" together you would understand how un-necessary is. You will basically make an environment that is no more secure but with more points of failure and more difficult to troubleshoot and administer. **Your time would be better spent making sure your ssh service itself was properly secured** with keys and such.

Comment: I think the flaw in your reasoning is that you assume I am 100% effective at configuring EC2 security groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aren't you being a little excessive? Your instances on EC2 are nicely isolated from other traffic by their own private firewall on the virtual network device you are "plugged into" upstream.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 5.5.5.5/32 --destination-port 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 22 -j REJECT
```

Comment: I want to verify that I am protected from other instances. I don't think this is excessive

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 22 -s 5.5.5.5 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT
```

This adds a rule which specifically allows access from that IP, then a rule which specifically denies it from everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

This has also been covered in very similar posts:
[Iptables: How to allow only one ip through specific port?](https://serverfault.com/questions/146569/iptables-how-to-allow-only-one-ip-through-specific-port)

[Allow traffic on one port from one IP address with iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/183240/allow-traffic-on-one-port-from-one-ip-address-with-iptables)

Comment: Right on, voting to close as dupe